# Controller is not being detected with $routerProvider configs

Tags: angularjs

So I am asking question after investing almost 2 hours to find the root cause of my problem.

**My Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Single Page Application</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="myApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/student">Student</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/courses">Courses</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**My myApp.js**

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller : 'HomeCntrl'        
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/student', {
        templateUrl : 'student.html',
        controller : 'StudentCntrl'        
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/courses', {
        templateUrl : 'courses.html',
        controller : 'CoursesCntrl'        
    });
}]);

    app.controller('HomeCntrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        alert("HomeCntrl");
        $scope.message = "Welcome to home page";    
    }]);

    app.controller('StudentCntrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        alert("StudentCntrl");
        $scope.message = "Welcome to Student page";    
    }]);

    app.controller('CoursesCntrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        alert("CoursesCntrl");
        $scope.message = "Welcome to Courses Page";    
    }]);
```

And some other htmls with code

```
 <h1>Home</h1>
    {{message}}

 <h1>Student Page</h1>
   {{message}}

 <h1>Courses Page</h1>
   {{message}}
```

I am using brackets to run this app. Let it be default hit or click over any link its always giving **alert("HomeCntrl")** only.

Note- The same code is running in plunker very well.

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG??

**Edit 1- Added screenshot of one click**
I clicked on Courses. But the popup I got is 'HomeCntrl'

[image]

**Edit 2 - Added my plunker link**

**Plunker Link**

http://plnkr.co/edit/HehCAD4afiN4xD828YYT?p=preview

**Edit 3** - Adding Screenshot of console

clicked on `Student` link

[image]

Comment: You have a typo. One is route and other is router. Fix the one in the function  argument.

Comment: its not making any difference. I deliberately put that. Tried with `$routeProvider`, still same.

Comment: Do you have templates for the rest of the two states(i.e. student and courses)?

Comment: Template?? Sorry I did not get you. You mean, screenshots of other two clicks? I added my plunker link in my post.

Comment: @cst1992, Templates added.

Comment: The plunker is indeed working as it should. The only things that come to my mind now are typos or console errors.

Comment: Sorry Its clean. Let me add screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to do an inject on your config and you also dont need to repeat $routeProvider. Change it to this.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Single Page Application</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="myApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Universal as universal">
    <ul>
      <li><span ng-click="universal.goTo('/')">Home</span></li>
      <li><span ng-click="universal.goTo('/student')">Students</span></li>
      <li><span ng-click="universal.goTo('/courses')">Courses</span></li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller : 'HomeCntrl'        
    })
   .when('/student', {
        templateUrl : 'student.html',
        controller : 'StudentCntrl'        
    })
    .when('/courses', {
        templateUrl : 'courses.html',
        controller : 'CoursesCntrl'        
    });
});

app.controller('Universal', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location){
       // alert("HomeCntrl");
       var scope = this;
        scope.goTo = function(where){
          $location.path(where)
        }    
    }]);

    app.controller('HomeCntrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
       // alert("HomeCntrl");
        $scope.message = "Welcome to home page";    
    }]);

    app.controller('StudentCntrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        alert("StudentCntrl");
        $scope.message = "Welcome to Student page";    
    }]);

    app.controller('CoursesCntrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        alert("CoursesCntrl");
        $scope.message = "Welcome to Courses Page";    
    }]);
```

What I did here was add a universal controller that you can use to handle routing. Make sure to inject $location so that it can navigate. When using angular routing you want to avoid using hrefs and use angularjs native routing. This code will work for you. Here is the [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/H1bUjo9EHBXAmgdtWvFp?p=preview) example I made.

Comment: This code is giving me compilation error. Do we need `]`? Tried removing that but got `[$injector:modulerr]`

Comment: Whoops remove the ]

Comment: Yeah then its giving `[$injector:modulerr]`

Comment: whoops there was a typo. you have router not route

Comment: Its same and `$routerProvider` is not a typo. Its just a variable name. I deliberately put that.

Comment: $routerProvider is not a real thing. $routeProvider is the correct injection.

Comment: Its still same. Sorry.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your angular error. I promise you the config I have provided will work but im unsure that the config is your problem

Comment: Updated the post with picture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152868/discussion-between-jaikrat-and-ohjay44).

Comment: Yeah, Its working. But whats wrong with my hyperlinks?

Answer (score 0):

Your latest screenshot shows what the problem is.
Look at the URL:

```
127.0.0.1:63688/index.html#!/#%2Fstudent
```

This means that the part `#/student` or `#/courses` is being blindly appended to the existing URL `127.0.0.1:63688/index.html#!/`. Since the required `#/` is there after the index.html you get shown your 'HomeCntrl'.

To get shown 'StudentCntrl' you need the URL to be:

```
127.0.0.1:63688/index.html#/student
```

On sites like Plunker, the index file is loaded by default, and it's not part of the URL. So if the index.html is removed from the URL, the page would still work:

```
127.0.0.1:63688/#/
```

Loading student URL changes it to

```
127.0.0.1:63688/#/student
```

Which then loads StudentCntrl.

Comment: What that `!` is doing there though, I have no idea.